# Why don't the weights in Recurrent Neural Networks change?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp, recurrent-neural-network

How the model learn without changing its parameters/ weights?
If we train the RNN on some data and then apply it to test data , what changes do we make ? Cause the weights/parameters don't change values right ?

Answer (score 0):

When we apply the model to the test data, we don't make any changes to the model at all.

At the test time (a.k.a. inference), we just take the inputs (in case of RNN, it is the current token of the input sequence, and the current memory state of the model), feed them into the fixed model (that is, multiply them by the fixed model weights and apply some nonlinearities), and get the outputs (in case of RNNs, it is the updated memory state, and the prediction for the current token). There is no need to learn or change anything at all.